# Vertically align faceted ggplots of different heights when using coord_equal()

Tags: r, ggplot2, gtable, cowplot

I am trying to combine two FACETED ggplot objects with `coord_equal()` using `cowplot::plot_grid()` or `egg::ggarrange()` and vertically align them.

The `egg::ggarrange()` approach works fine for UNFACETED plots, with the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924219/vertically-align-of-plots-of-different-heights-using-cowplotplot-grid-when-u).

However, the `egg::ggarrange()` solution breaks down when faceting is included. **The plots are correctly aligned, but the units of the y-axes are twice as large as those of the x-axes**. Any suggestions for how to generalize this for faceting?

```
dat1 <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10, 2), y = 1:20, z = rep(c("A", "B"), 10))
dat2 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, z = rep(c("A", "B"), 5))
plot1 <- ggplot(dat1, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point() + coord_equal() + facet_wrap(~z)
plot2 <- ggplot(dat2, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point() + coord_equal() + facet_wrap(~z)
egg::ggarrange(plot1, plot2, ncol = 1)
```

[image: image 1]

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48549294/get-same-height-for-plots-having-different-facet-numbers-and-coord-fixed) might be an overkill for the current example but some very nice insights can be found in the answer.

Comment: Have you tried the `patchwork` package? `library(patchwork); plot1 / plot2`  The packages is not on CRAN (yet), to install it, run `library(devtools); devtools::install_github("thomasp85/patchwork")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems to be a simple fix,

```
library(egg)

b <- body(gtable_frame)
b[6] <- parse(text="if (fixed_ar) {
    ar <- as.numeric(g$heights[tt[1]]) / as.numeric(g$widths[ll[1]])
    height <- width * (ar / length(ll))
    g$respect <- FALSE
}")

body(gtable_frame) <- b

assignInNamespace("gtable_frame", gtable_frame, ns = 'egg')
```

[image]

Comment: So are you suggesting a modification of egg::gtable_frame()? I'm guessing this is called by egg::ggarrange()? I guess I could suggest this change to the package's maintainer? I'm not sure if this "fix" is universal or should just be an option for when fixed/equal coords are desired.

Comment: I've suggested this fix to the maintainer of egg.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that `plot1` and `plot2` have different aspect ratios.
This is `plot1`:
[image]

And this `plot2`:

[image]

You can try to keep the aspect ratio using, i.e. `theme(aspect.ratio=1)` instead of `coord_equal()`:

```
require(ggplot2)
dat1 <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10, 2), y = 1:20, z = rep(c("A", "B"), 10))
dat2 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, z = rep(c("A", "B"), 5))
plot1 <- ggplot(dat1, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + theme(aspect.ratio=1)+
  facet_wrap(~z)
plot2 <- ggplot(dat2, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + theme(aspect.ratio=1)+
  facet_wrap(~z)
egg::ggarrange(plot1, plot2, ncol = 1,heights = c(1,10))
```

[image]

Hope it serves.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The point is to maintain the aspect ratios of the two plots.